# Se puede ejecutar aplicaciones de Windows en Android?

Tags: terminal

Puede Wine ejecutar aplicaciones de Windows en Android con Termux

Comment: No lo sé. Podríamos probarlo.

Comment: Puedes experimentar un poco con tu termux?Mateo

Comment: Encontré este tutorial. https://youtu.be/6z95TJZ7NBQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta es si y no.
Android es un sistema basado en linux por lo que en teoria se podria instalar Wine, en la version adecuada a tu dispositivo. Wine te va a permitir instalar aplicaciones windows en linux, macos o por lo que pides android.
El problema de esto es que las aplicaciones de windows estan hechas para funcionar en windows con las caracteristicas de un ordenador :).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar windows en android a través de termux
[https://www.geekydrive.com/2020/10/how-to-run-windows-10-on-termux-on.html#:~:text=After%20download%20and%20installing%20the%20Limbo%20Emulator%20App,type%20%E2%80%9Cpkg%20install%20qemu-system-x86_64%20%E2%80%9D%20and%20press%20enter](https://www.geekydrive.com/2020/10/how-to-run-windows-10-on-termux-on.html#:%7E:text=After%20download%20and%20installing%20the%20Limbo%20Emulator%20App,type%20%E2%80%9Cpkg%20install%20qemu-system-x86_64%20%E2%80%9D%20and%20press%20enter).

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/395747)